# How to check if the distribution of some variables, is the same between the original dataset and the subset one in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset `dt`. I take a subsample of it using `dt_subsample = dt.sample(frac=0.3, random_state=42)`.

I would like to check, if the distribution of specific variables (lets say `var1`, `var2` and `var3`) is the same between `dt` and `dt_subsample`

`var1`, `var2` and `var3` can be either categorical or numerical

sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

dt = pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.random.randint(1, 6, 10000), 'var2': np.random.randint(10, 20, 10000), 'var3': list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 10000))})
```

Answer (score 3):

### Theory

If we want to check, if two data series are part of the same distribution, we can use the [Two-Sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), which measures the maximum distance between the empirical cumulative distribution functions of two data series.

[image: Wikipedia: Two-Sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov-Test]

### Implementation

[Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) provides an implementation of that test:

```python
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

for col in dt.columns:
    print(ks_2samp(dt[col], dt_subsample[col]))
```

```
var1 Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.013866666666666666, pvalue=1.0)
var2 Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.009533333333333333, pvalue=1.0)
var3 Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.009066666666666667, pvalue=1.0)
```

### Interpretation

Two *identical* data series would give us a statistic value of 0 (*"the maximum distance between the two CDF"*) and a p value of 1 (*"how sure we can be that based on the data we have this is true"*).

So in order to be sure that two data series origin from the same distribution, we're looking for low statistic values and high p values.

Or as the scipy documentation puts it:

> If the KS statistic is small or the p-value is high, then we cannot reject the hypothesis that the distributions of the two samples are the same.